# how to check Java is running inside a container enviroment by Java

Tags: java, docker

I need to check is my `springboot` is running in a `docker` container or not. I am doing it as following. I don't know if `.dockerenv` is always on root or not. If it is not correct. How to do it by java?

```
public static boolean isRunningInsideDocker() {
    if(Files.exists(Path.of("/.dockerenv"))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tired it and isRunningInsideDocker always return flase even under continaer.

Comment: Did you look at the content of `/proc/1/cgroup`? Maybe in your container runtime the content differs, but it is certainly possible to see if you are running in a container using that information.

Comment: cat /proc/1/cgroup in real ubuntu  `0::/init.scope`. And in docker it is `0::/`. So his comment doens't matach.

Comment: Also reaing the file from Java mgiht be diffcult becuse of root access and permision matter.

Comment: In no container runtime I know of, it is `0::/` in docker. Are you sure you are running in docker and using the official docker runtime? Also reading the information is allowed for all users and this is not a actual file but process information provided by the kernel!

Comment: Tasted for 3 diff docker type as `FROM ubuntu:latest`, `FROM ubuntu:latest` and  `FROM postgres:10-alpine`. All has same cat ` cat /proc/1/cgroup` return `0::/`